# Array.find() taking too long, bad user experience, node.js

Tags: android, node.js, performance, socket.io, user-experience

> This is not a question about concurrency or event loop of node

I have a question in how to magane a scenario in wich thosands of users are connected by socket and autentified by jswtoken to a Node.js server.

Let´s say there are between 10,000 and 50,000 users connected throught an Android app with socket.io client, all of them are pushed into an array `users.push(newUser)` when the connection is stablished by socket.io and removed on disconnect, `users.splice(id,1)` no problem there.

But all of them wants to update a var on his respctive object in the array each 5 seconds

I can idetify their respective object by his `user.id` using `Array.prototype.find()` but it takes too long.

In my tests `(mocha,chai)` it takes, to find and update X users:

- For 1,000 users , 2XXX.XX ms (more than 2 seconds)
- For 10,000 users , 4XXX.XX ms (more than 4 seconds)
- For 25,000 users , 3XXXX.XX ms (more than 30 seconds)

Over that 4 seconds there is no way to keep a real time experience.
Is there any design pattern to walkaround this? 
I have a few ideas but no one seems to be practical and scalable

1. Store in the client the position it is using currently (is not good because each time a user is disconnected i have to notify all other if index has changed or not)
2. Separate the users in multiple arrays of maximum 1000 positions and relate them to another mapping to do the `.find()` function directly on a relatively small array to search. (I don´t know if it is a good practice but the task of identify users relay on the server and it doesn´t take too long)
3. Totaly abandon Node and look for another solution (I would like to keep it in Node)

Comment: Is actually required to be an **array** of users? Why not some other data structure that is faster to read data?

Comment: What would be better? I emit the changes of this array to a graphic for an admin in a web browser, thats way i store this data as an array. What should i do?

Comment: Maybe `.filter()` can be a bit faster than `.find()`, but for your specific case where every user has a unique `id`, and you are searching only by this value, would be better and way faster, to have them in a `Object`, like: `{userId1: {}, userId2:{}}`.

Comment: `filter()` takes a little more, because doesn't stop if it find an element that pass the filter, it keep searching for more elements that can pass the test and as far as i understand `find()` stops when a element pass the condition. The second option looks efective, let me try it. Thanks for your time

Comment: You can go for it. It's guaranteed that searching for `users[userId]` will be really faster.

Comment: As you said, it is faster, but does not fit the requirements of my situation

Answer (score 0):

I don't think theres a simple answer to this question. Having 10 000 - 50 000 active users at the same time in a chat / game / what ever? Thats a massive payload and I really don't think your app has to worry about that kind of traffic.

Comment: Even with a smaller amount, let´s say 1000 users online, the chat/game is responding as expected, good performance so far, but im worried if the amount of concurrent users increases and the performance is dropped.
To explain a little more my situation I have decided to keep the data emited by each clien in his respective sockets to a mongo db and keep track of the clients and his respective rooms there, should i avoid this and keep all user data directly in the sockets? will this improve performance? Maybe this is another question.